# MVC3 - How do I route to a subsite?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a subsite within my main site for site Administration.  The site is physically stored in the form

> ~/Views/Administration/ViewName/Index

With controllers inside

> ~/Controllers/Admin/ControllerName

I am getting an exception trying to visit the page.

> The view 'index' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/ViewName/index.aspx ~/Views/ViewName/index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/index.aspx ~/Views/Shared/index.ascx
>   ~/Views/ViewName/index.cshtml ~/Views/ViewName/index.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/index.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/index.vbhtml

I added a route

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                "Administration", // Route name
                "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Administration", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Going directly to the page manually

> http://localhost:999/Administration/BaseItem/index

Does not result in exception, but I get no content.  This leads me to believe it is not finding the View.  What am I doing wrong?

---

I think the issue is that I have told the route engine how to route to the Controller, but I have not told the system how to route to the View.  Where do I tell the system where the views are?

Comment: Is that maproute the first one in the global.asax or have you put it after the default? (If so the default is likely matching first...)

Comment: @Timbo It comes after.  I changed it to before.  I still get a blank screen, but I'm not seeing any errors.

Comment: Cool, yep, the default was matching it before then. You have to order your config as most specific to least specific. I think the blank screen sounds like a separate issue.

Comment: @Timbo - Apologies, actually the errors are still there.  They just showed up in my email late (I catch and throw out emails in global.asax).

Comment: it looks like it is treating "ViewName" as the controller, hence the feeling that it's a routing issue. In the /Administration/BaseItem/Index url you should be resolving a controller called BaseItem and a view called Index, found in ~/Views/BaseItem/Index, if the routemaps are right. Is that the correct structure of your controller / views?

Comment: The structure is listed in the question.  The url is correct.  The view is in ~/Views/Administration/BaseItem/Index.  http://localhost:29286/Administration/BaseItem/Index does hit the breakpoint in my controller.  So the issue is the view is not found (as indicated by the error).  I believe you are correct that my route is incorrect, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the routes, but with the design.  The view engine cannot find your view, because it cannot find the correct path, since the default view engines are not designed to search for a subsite.

Instead of creating a subsite, make Administration an `Area` in your project.  In `AdministrationAreaRegistration.cs`, you will set a route similar to the route you added.  Place your views in the Views folder inside the Administration folder (inside the Area folder), and everything will work properly.

Comment: Hm.  Yea that is what I am trying to do, conceptually.  Though, adding this really changes my perspective on the whole design.  I am concerned that I need to duplicate my Models across the main site and the area site.

Comment: Since an Area is part of the same project, it will have available all of the same namespaces as the controllers and views outside of the Areas folder.  I can't see any reason models would need to be duplicated.

Comment: Ok, I saw the project added its own set of Controller/model/view folders and a web.config.  I just assumed it wouldn't see the ones from the "main project" any longer.  I stand corrected.

Comment: Just a small note to anyone doing this conversion.  The Areas are driven by Namespaces.  If you have existing controllers and move them into the Area...you need to manually update the Namespace to make them work.  The namespace is of the form `Project.Areas.AreaName.Controllers`.  Or, simply add a new Controller temporarily and copy/paste the namespace over existing controllers.